# Image Slider Non working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, events, slider

the code below dose not work right. I want an image slider that changes every 5 seconds, but if I hover over it it will stop and when i leave it starts again. When you click on it it will change. I can make it change every 5 seconds, and change it when i click, but i cant get it to stop when I hover.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var img = 0;
    var pic = ['nature', 'grass', 'earth', 'fall', 'fall2'];
    var slider = 'img.slide_img'; // html image

    function slide() {
        $(slider).attr('src', 'pictures/' + pic[img] + '.jpg');
        img++;
        if (img >= pic.length) {
            img = 0;
        }
    }

    $(slider).on('mouseleave', function() {
        auto(3000);
    });

    $(slider).on('click', function() {
        slide();
    });

    function auto(time) {
        setInterval(function() {
            slide();
        }, time)
    }   
});
```

Comment: Well, what does "it doesn't work" mean? Does it not do anything? Give an error? Crash your computer? Make waffles fall from the sky? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of problems:

1. You don't initialise your `setInterval` so that it only starts when triggering the `mouseleave` event.
2. Every time the `mouseleave` event is triggered you start a new `setInterval` so you'll probably end up having multiple running at the same time.
3. Your desired behaviour is that hovering over the image will stop the slider, but you don't have anything in place to do that.

How's this: http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/uLAYB/

```
var img = 0,
    pic = ['nature', 'grass', 'earth', 'fall', 'fall2'],
    slider = $('img.slide_img'),
    timerID = 0,
    delay = 2000;

function slide() {
    slider.attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/200x200&text=' + pic[img]);
    img++;
    if (img >= pic.length) {
        img = 0;
    }
}

slider.on('mouseleave', function () {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    auto();
});

slider.on('mouseenter', function () {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
});

slider.on('click', function () {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    slide();
});

function auto() {
    timerID = setTimeout(function () {
        slide();
        auto();
    }, delay);
}

auto();
```

Notice I'm using 'clearTimeout' to prevent multiple timeouts running at the same time:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout